# Plotting the average of multiple time series objects and illustrating the error from that plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series, facet

Consider `dat` created here:

```r
set.seed(123)
ID = factor(letters[seq(6)])
time = c(100, 102, 120, 105, 109, 130)
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(ID,time), Time = sequence(time))
dat$group <- rep(c("GroupA","GroupB"), c(322,344))
dat$values <- sample(100, nrow(dat), TRUE)
```

`dat` contains time series data for 6 individuals (6 `ID`s), which belong to 2 groups (`GroupA` and `GroupB`). Assume that we expect the time series within each group to have similar properties. Also note that the time series for each individual is of different length. We essentially want to create an "average" time series plot of each group, which I have done like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = max(Time)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = min(maxtime)) %>%
  group_by(group, Time) %>%
  summarize(values = mean(values)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, values, colour = group))+ 
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(.~group)
```

[image]

How can we do this same thing, but add the original plots for each individual behind the "average" plots to illustrate the error associated with each "average"? Note that The way I created the "average plot" was by using the length of the `ID` with the shortest time series from each group, but when the originals are added, I would like to see the whole plots from the originals if possible (so some will be longer than others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a second `geom_line` you can plot the "raw" data in the background as e.g. grey lines.

```r
set.seed(123)
ID = factor(letters[seq(6)])
time = c(100, 102, 120, 105, 109, 130)
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(ID,time), Time = sequence(time))
dat$group <- rep(c("GroupA","GroupB"), c(322,344))
dat$values <- sample(100, nrow(dat), TRUE)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
d <- dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = max(Time)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = min(maxtime)) %>%
  group_by(group, Time) %>%
  summarize(values = mean(values))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'group' (override with `.groups` argument)

ggplot()+ 
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(Time, values, group = ID), color = "grey80", alpha = .7) +
  geom_line(data = d, aes(Time, values, colour = group)) +
  facet_wrap(.~group)
```

[image]

Comment: this is like what I am looking for thanks. this code works fine, but when i try to apply it to my real data, when i do the `ggplot()` call, it says `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'values' not found`. any ideas why? I cant seem to figure it out

Comment: if i try `ggplot(mapping = aes(idx, d$values))+`, it returns `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (26694): y`. in this case `idx` is the same thing as `Time`

Comment: Hm. I just can guess. From the error message it's clear that the variable `values` is missing in the original data set `dat` or in the summarized dataset which I called `d`. Therefore check whether `values` is present in both datasets. And no. don't use d$values in the call to ggplot. The first geom_line uses the var `values` from `dat`, the second the var `values` from `d`.

Comment: so in your code, in the first line of the `ggplot()` call (`ggplot(mapping = aes(Time, values))+` ), are `Time` and `values` here referring to the data in `dat` or `d`? I think this may be where I am messing up

Comment: (: Probably this use of the aes is a bit confusing. I just made an edit to make the code less confusing. The first geom_line uses dat as data and takes vars Time, values and ID from this dataset. The second one uses the vars Time, values and group from dataset d.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a composed plot like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
G1 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = max(Time)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = min(maxtime)) %>%
  group_by(group, Time) %>%
  summarize(values = mean(values)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, values, colour = group))+ 
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(.~group)+
  ylab('Mean')
G2 <- dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = max(Time)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(maxtime = min(maxtime)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Time, values, colour = group))+ 
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(.~group)+
  ylab('Real Values')
#Compose plots
G3 <- G2/G1+plot_layout(guides = "collect")
```

Output:

[image]